# How to alter position of text inside a table / td? with CSS only if possible

Tags: html, css, html-table

[Preview wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1OFE.png)

[image]

A client wants to have the table designed like this above.

But I cant seem to figure out how to alter the position of the text in the first row or better said in general, because things like `margin-top: -20px;` just don't work...

Also client will have employees create tables with non-HTML knowledge like Gutenberg Editor Table. This means I don't really have the option to add an extra element inside the td like a span.

Any idea how and if this is doable?

I have to work with whatever HTML the Wordpress Gutenberg Editor is putting out. Which looks like this at the end:

```html
<figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Kopf 1</td>
                <td>kopf 2</td>
                <td>kopf 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z1a</td>
                <td>z1b</td>
                <td>z1c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z2a</td>
                <td>z2b</td>
                <td>z2c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z3</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z4</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z5</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>z6</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</figure>
```

So: this puts out no `<thead>` and it wraps the whole thing inside a `<figure>`... I know its awful, but i try to find a compromise in altering super easy to use gutenberg modules (or lazy blocks) with CSS, so dummy users can build content, that is styled individually in the background. Creating Tables is one of the more difficult points.

CSS:

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td {

???

}
```

I tried

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td {

margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: -20px;

}
```

to alter the position but that doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty horrible design but you would have to wrap the text in an element and then move it  into position.

Comment: Yes, wrap the content into an extra element (then you can still use the `td` itself for the background color), and move the additional element using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Comment: Shouldn't you modify the items inside `thead`? If you can, please, provide the HTML of the table

Comment: i tried "transform: translate(-20px,-20px)" but if you move stuff outside of the table it gets cut off :/ 

https://imgur.com/a/xXQDae0

Comment: @meniK you should add how you are embedding the table in your page.. because it looks like an iframe cropping the content. As you can see from the answers given (for sure mine) there's no cropping happening like the picture you shared there

Comment: Please share your HTML. That will impact any solution.

Comment: @TylerH the HTML this Wordpress Gutenberg Editor Table module puts out looks like this:

<figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular"><table><tbody><tr><td>Kopf 1</td><td>kopf 2</td><td>kopf 3</td></tr><tr><td>z1a</td><td>z1b</td><td>z1c</td></tr><tr><td>z2a</td><td>z2b</td><td>z2c</td></tr><tr><td>z3</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr><tr><td>z4</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr><tr><td>z5</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr><tr><td>z6</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody></table></figure>

i cant define thead in any way for example :(

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the texts on the first line in `<span>` and assigning `position: absolute` with `top: -20px` in them and `position: relative` in the `<td>`

EDIT:

Using javascript to wrap the text with span

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  cells.forEach(function(cell) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = cell.textContent;
    cell.textContent = '';
    cell.appendChild(span);
  });
});
```

Comment: the problem is... i try to build this by CSS only so a table generated with Gutenberg Editor (or similar) will have this look... 

guess i would need some JS to inject a <span> ? (not very familiar with JS yet... )

Comment: ok, if you can't directly change the HTML, it needs to be done with javascript. I edited the answer with the code

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the design you want you can simply modify the appearance of the `thead` element, I suggest you to use `position: relative;` and `top: -.5em;`.
Of course, you can also act on `td`s directly, but be sure to encapsulate the content in a contanier, e.g. a `<span>`.

Here it is a snippet with some examples:

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
th > span {
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
.myclass {
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
tr > td:nth-child(2) > span {
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col"><span>B</span></th>
      <th class="myclass">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data A</td>
      <td>data B</td>
      <td class="myclass">data C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data A1</td>
      <td><span>data B1</span></td>
      <td><span class="myclass">data C1</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments and other answers, the point here is having the `<th>` content displaced relative to its box model. I'm doing my answer just for the sake of having a live snippet but I'm adding close to nothing to anything said already.

There are mostly two ways to achieve that result:

- By styling the `<th>` as `position: relative` and then having a child
  element styled as `position: absolute` so that its actual position
  will cross the border box of the container;
- By still having a child element with text content styled with a
  [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate);

Here in this demo I'm showing the translate strategy. There are some tricks to keep things tidy up; for example the size of the `th` and `td` are stated statically to keep alignments correct and the word wrap is forced with a `br` both in the header text and in some td contents. The font is the closest I could pick that could be taken for granted and yet look close to the picture given.. that's clearly a sans serif font but of course it should be more condensed.

And now 2 further notes:

- I noticed in a comment of yours you stated that you cannot change the
  html and you might be forced to create such child element inside each
  `th` via js. It sounds strange you can't change the html by the way
  even if you are using a wysiwyg editor. But as suggested in the other
  answer, you can just have a js function running on `DOMContentLoaded`
  that will replace the `th` content with a new element wrapping it;
- You also said in a latest comment that the table gets cropped around
  its box model... that's not clear why and it may depend on how it's
  embedded in the page and you didn't show in your question so far;

To say the whole truth there's sill another way that would not need the html to be changed (well only slightly actually): using css rules adopting `::before`/`::after` to add the displaced element on top of the `th`. I didn't add this way because it would be required only if the html way isn't suitable in your scenario.

```css
table{
  font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', Arial, sans-serif;  
  font-size: 10pt;

  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4em;    
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead th{  
  background-color: #E0EAED; 
  width: 14em;  
  max-width: 14em;  
  height: 2em;  
}

table thead th > .header{          
  height: 3em;  
  transform: translate(-.8em,-.7em);  
  text-align: left;    
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #E0EAED; 
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

table tbody td{  
  height: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="header">GRÖSSENBEZEICHNUNG</div></th>
      <th><div class="header">ACHSSTIFTBREITE</div></th>
      <th><div class="header">DECKBREITE IDEAL</div></th>
      <th><div class="header">DECKBREITE<br>MAXIMAL</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>109 Standard<br>T-Hangar</td>
      <td>7" (179 mm)</td>
      <td>6.775"–7.025"</td>
      <td>6.65"–7.15"</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>129 Low</td>
      <td>7.625" (194 mm)</td>
      <td>7.5"–7.75"</td>
      <td>7.375"–7,875"</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed answer! I really appreciate you taking the time. The whole base problem is, that dummy users will be trained to use the Table-Module from Gutenberg Editor. If you create a table like this, what Gutenberg edit puts out is this:

<figure class="wp-block-table is-style-regular"><table><tbody><tr><td>Kopf 1</td><td>kopf 2</td><td>kopf 3</td>..... 

So it wraps the table inside this <figure> tag and doesnt even us <thead> - i know its awful... i am working on preparing different modules, that are as easy to use as possible for dummies, but are styled css.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers seem to have concentrated on moving the text.

I would leave the text alone and instead alter the background of that first row.

The reason for doing it this way is that the system adjusts the height of the greyish bit to accommodate any extra lines that may be put in the column headings.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)>td {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

tr:first-child>td {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 0.7em, #eeeeee 0.7em 100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A<br>B<br>more<br>more</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thats an interesting approach! Thanks i will look into this.